Connecting PyCharm to remote: cannot install PyCharm backend
I wish to connect my PyCharm with a remote host whose admins restrict that all jobs must be submitted in job batches. Nonetheless, my sole purpose of using PyCharm to connect with that remote is such that I could edit my codes in the IDE I'm more familiar with and save time. The admin has approved me of using PyCharm and has added PyCharm to the allowed URL list for download. However, my PyCharm could successfully connect to the remote via SSH, but could not "configure the backend on remote". The problem seemes to be that PyCharm is unable to download the necessary binary for it to work on the remote. I have heard of other people using VSCode to successfully connect and work on the same remote, but I'm afraid I'm the first one who ever tries PyCharm and others have no experience at all on my problem. I do not use VSCode for now solely on personal preference.
(P.S.: When choosing the "working directory" on remote from my PyCharm interface I chose my personal directory on the remote, which did NOT include a Python interpreter; all interpreters and softwares on this remote must be loaded via batch script before use. I'm not sure if this could be the issue. )
Based on this hypothesis I have suggested the best way is for me to log in to the remote separately (eg. via a separate SSH shell), then switch my connection manually to a computing node (where more intensive works are allowed) and download the required backend binary of PyCharm myself. However, I've checked materials online and there is no walkthrough on this available.
It would be greatly appreciated if anyone with better knowledge on remote server and computer science overall could offer some insights. Thanks in advance.
My PyCharm version is Professional 2024.1. I'm not entirely sure of the configuration of my remote other than it is clearly one of the Linux distributions.
